# Добавление дополнительного условия (условий) в sed

Tags: регулярные-выражения, sed

пытаюсь разобраться с **sed**, есть определенная задача по поиску совпадений в файле
для примера:
`sed -n '/t/!p' file_for_sed.txt` - Вывожу все строки не содержащие буквы t
Как я могу в этот же код добавить еще условие, скажем так же запретить выводить строки с буквой z
Пробовал делать через скобки `(/t/!p)|(/z/!p)`, но ничего не вышло, попытался поискать, но не нашел

Comment: `sed -n '/[tz]/!p' file_for_sed.txt`?

Comment: Дааа, огромное спасибо! Буду разбираться дальше)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте скобочное выражение ("bracket expression"):

```bsh
sed -n '/[tz]/!p' file_for_sed.txt
```

Здесь скобочное выражение `[tz]` находит `t` или `z`.

Если `t` или `z` — это многосимвольные строки, используйте оператор ИЛИ, доступный в POSIX ERE:

```bsh
sed -nE '/t...|z.../!p' file_for_sed.txt
```

GNU sed:

```bsh
sed -n '/t...\|z.../!p' file_for_sed.txt
```

Если ваше выражение часть более длинного выражения:

```bsh
sed -nE '/...(t...|z...).../!p' file_for_sed.txt
sed -n '/...\(t...\|z..\).../!p' file_for_sed.txt
```